# how to check items in checkboxlist?

Tags: asp.net

i have a checkboxlist that i want to check some of it's items,
items that i wanna check store in database, i'm selecting them from database and in a loop i wrote thees but just last item selected :(( :

```
var selectedRoles = (from r in DataContext.Context.Core_PagesPermission 
                     where r.PageName.Contains(pageName) select r)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
if(selectedRoles != null)
{
     string roles = selectedRoles.Roles;
     string[] role = roles.Split(',');
     int countTags = role.Count();
     foreach (string word in role)
     {
        CheckBoxList1.SelectedValue = word;
        Response.Write(word + "<br/>");
        countTags -= 1;
     }
 }
```

this worked :

```
var selectedRoles = (from r in DataContext.Context.Core_PagesPermission where r.PageName.Contains(pageName) select r)
                            .FirstOrDefault();
                        dsRoles.DataBind();
                        CheckBoxList1.DataBind();
                        if(selectedRoles != null)
                        {
                        string roles = selectedRoles.Roles;
                        string[] role = roles.Split(',');
                        foreach (string word in role)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                CheckBoxList1.Items.FindByValue(word).Selected = true;
                            }
                            catch (Exception exp)
                            {
                                lbError.Text= exp.ToString();
                            }
```

Comment: could you please be more precise with your question. am i right with the assumption: you have a checkboxlist displaying ALL permission, and you want to check those permissions stores in DB?

Comment: yes sorry for my pure English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to select the individual items:

```
CheckBoxList1.Items.FindByText(word).Selected = true;
```

or

```
CheckBoxList1.Items.FindByValue(word).Selected = true;
```

However, if the checkboxlist doesn't have the text/value you are looking for, it will throw an error.

Comment: You can also loop through the entire list and do a comparison to each 'word' in your list and select the checkbox that way.   `for(int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; i++)  
{  
 if(CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Text == word)  
  { CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected = true; }  
}`  Use .Text or .Value to compare and look for the value you are missing, difference in spelling or why it is throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

datatable method checkboxlist

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    chkCategories.Items.FindByValue(dt.Rows[i]["CategoryID"].ToString()).Selected = true;   
}
```